# Can GCM cloud server access my app server database table?

Tags: google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

I am using google cloud messaging in my web based android application. I want to send a message to all of my android apps through gcm (one by one, not simultaneously). Commonly, my web server sends request to gcm with data and then gcm sends that data to particular app. So if my database contains records of 10 apps then my web server will request gcm 10 times. Is there a way that my web server gives access of database table to gcm. Then gcm using that database table send messages to apps one by one. So my web server does not need to request the gcm server 10 times. Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance for your kind reply!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way Google can access your database, but you can send multicast messages to up to 1000 recipients using the `registration_ids` parameter instead of `to` in you HTTP request.

See also https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#downstream

Upd.: you can also subscribe all your clients to a single topic and then send to that topic.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Comment: Can i send a multicast message to gcm and gcm does not send the message to all devices simultaneously. Rather it sends the message to all devices one by one after 5 seconds etc. Is it possible?

Comment: @SaifBajwa no, there is no such functionality. If you want to avoid overloading your server, you should be able to implement a random delay with backoff on the client for that

Comment: @SaifBajwa note that I've updated my answer with topics